# How to broadcast scipy.stat's hypergeom cdf over shape parameters?

Tags: python, scipy, broadcast

The documentation of scipy.stats.hypergeom shows how to broadcast the probability mass function (pmf) over the number k of successes when one draws N objects from M, out of which n are marked:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import hypergeom
M,n,N=[20,7,12]
k=np.arange(8)
print hypergeom.pmf(k,M,n,N)
```

yields the desired output of an array of probabilities.

Now I need to evaluate the probability of finding **up to** k items, say k=1, when the number of marked items is variable, say from 0 to M=20 in this example. When I try the same type of broadcast for the **cumulative distribution function cdf**

```
q=np.arange(M+1)
print hypergeom.cdf(1,M,q,N)
```

this gives the error message "TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars".

I am puzzled, since the [reference guide of Scipy v0.14.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html) states that both the random variable k and the shape parameters are array-like. Curiously, the [doc of scipy v0.19.1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html) does not mention the variable types anymore. Anyhow, the error message appears for both versions. Any help on how to broadcast the **cdf** over shape parameters is appreciated!

Edit: changed **pmf** (where broadcasting turns out to work fine in scipy's newer versions) to **cdf** (where it doesn't).

Comment: I didn't get an error when I tried this with scipy 0.19.1.

Comment: My mistake: I only tried with scipy 0.17.0, but referred to the latest doc. I will update, then. Thank you for checking. Just for my education: what went wrong in the older versions, although the parameters supposedly could be array-like? And is there a simple way to avoid the error in older versions?